# Require module node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I'm writing a wrapper for a private api. This api only accepts https requests and thus I need to send https requests to make it work. I'm using browserify to bundle up the .js-files. The problem is that the https module seems to noe be loaded properly along with the other modules, like the http modules. After the code beneath has been run, the `https` variable is undefined, while the `http` variable is defined as one would expect. Any ideas on what could be wrong here?

```
function(require, module, exports){
  (function (process,Buffer){
    var optional = require('./lib/optional')
      , http = require('http')
      , https = optional('https');
      // ...
```

Comment: what do you have in `./lib/optional`?

Comment: I removed most of your code, because it was irrelevant to your question. Please, edit the question if you think that I removed too much of it.